# How can I `draw` something on a JavaFX WritableImage?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm migrating a project from Swing to JavaFX, and I have a problem. Since `java.awt.BufferedImage` provides `getGraphics` and it has lots of convenient methods (like `drawLine`, `drawImage`, etc.), I have some codes that uses these features.

But in JavaFX' `WritableImage`, I can't find any similar methods.
Did I miss something? Or should I use something else instead of `WritableImage`?

Comment: If you're going to use a framework you might as well use [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which is specifically made for creating games and has a lot of active members (like me!) around the 'net. Much more so than JavaFX from what I've seen anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getGraphics` in `BufferedImage` and do all the drawing job in the `BufferedImage`, and use `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage` to convert it into a `WritableImage`.

It's slow, and I have an alternative.

Draw everything on a `Canvas`, and use this:

```
override val screenCut get() =
  JvmImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(canvas.snapshot(
      SnapshotParameters(), null), null))
```

This will probably help.